# Can I trigger variation selection from an external button?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a site where a product has 3 separate variations each with different price points. For some reason I need to be able allow the user to select from a series of options with some of them sharing variations.

For example, option A,B,C will be for variation 1, while option D and F will be for variation 2. Can I set the variation through java script?

**To prevent over complication, I just want to be able to switch the variation by clicking a button.**

Comment: In the cart or at the product page? Please add a screenshot for explanation too.

Comment: Its in the product page. To prevent over complication, I just want to be able to switch the variation by clicking a button.

Comment: I would like to help but I don't really understand what you need. Maybe you should edit your question. Add some images describing your idea for example.

Comment: Normally, you switch the variations using the drop down select on the product's page. When the variation drop down select is changed, the price is modified. For reasons, I need to be able to trigger this change from a separate drop down. When that drop down is changed, I need the original drop down to change with it. Right now, I have some js that checks if the separate drop down changes and if so, to change the original drop down. However, this isn't properly changing the variation as clicking "add to cart" results in an error stating the variation information is wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
jQuery('#session').change()
```

This was the line of code I needed to trigger the event.